# Regular grammars

Tags: regular-expressions, simulation

I am fairly new to automata, regular expressions and regular grammar. I am struggling to understand how to define the regular expression **(abc)*** into one or several regular grammar expressions.
Following production rules are applied

1. N={S,A,B}
2. Σ={a, b c}
3. S being the start symbol

So far i have found these two.

> S → aA
>
> A → bB
>
> B → cS
>
> S → ε

and

> S → Ac
>
> A → Bb
>
> B → Sa
>
> S → ε

Are both of the grammars over correct or do i have the wrong idea? I just dont understand why the two grammars over are correct while the bottom two are not.

> S → aA
>
> A → bB
>
> B → cS
>
> B → c

and

> S → Ac
>
> A → Bb
>
> B → Sa
>
> B → a

Comment: Looks fine to me. What doubts did you have that this wasn't right? By the way, two things: (1) Welcome to the site! (2) These "check my results" posts are discouraged here; we'll be happy to clear up things you don't quite understand, but in those cases you should help us help you by pointing out where you don't get what's going on.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome! I understand, i didn't know quite how to formulate myself. I will articulate the question better next time. Well the reason why i was wondering if wasn't right was because of the test i ran in JFLAP. First i generated random strings using my regular expression (abc)* then i tested those for match using the regular grammar expressions. Two of them had full match while the two i listed here didn't. I got confused to as why that would happen if they were the same in the first place. I hope that made sense.

Comment: I don't understand what "full match" means but it scarcely matters--your answer is correct. It might be nice to edit your original post to include your clarifying comment. Who knows? Maybe there's a JFLAP expert here who'll say "Yeah, that's a known bug, they say they're working on a fix."

Comment: Would you care to explain why the two solutions on top are correct while the two a the bottom are not?

Comment: Is the empty string in the language with the first two grammars? Is it in the languages generated by the third and fourth?